# TensorFlow: How to wrap a value as a scalar Tensor rather than a 1x1 Tensor

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have the following code, trying to wrap a `bool` value into tensorflow::Tensor.

```
tensorflow::Tensor vector_to_tensor_bool(const std::vector<bool> &input_vec) {
    tensorflow::Tensor tensor_1d(tensorflow::DT_BOOL, tensorflow::TensorShape({1}));
    auto tensor_1d_map = tensor_1d.tensor<bool, 1>();
    tensor_1d_map(0) = input_vec[0];
    return tensor_1d;
}
```

However, the I got the error:

```
 Caused by: Invalid argument: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [1]
```

I think it is saying I should just make it a scalar tensor, not a 1x1 Tensor. How do I convert a regular value to a scalar Tensor value? Thanks!